FATAL ERROR: JavaScript heap out of memory only when deployed in Azure container apps
I have deployed the same (no code change) Node.js application in both Docker containers and Azure Container Apps. I've noticed a discrepancy in memory usage between the two environments.
In Azure Container Apps, the application's Memory Working Set Bytes continually increases, showing no fluctuations. Once it reaches 2GB, I encounter the following error: FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory. and once after restart it starts from 115 MB and works fine till it reaches 2 GB.
Conversely, in Docker containers, the Memory Working Set Bytes graph fluctuates, and I do not encounter this error.
I have attached a graph for reference: Comparison of Azure Container Apps (White) and Docker Container (Black) Memory Working Set Bytes Graph
I have got the v8.getHeapStatistics() for
Docker container:

{
total_heap_size: 6582272,
total_heap_size_executable: 524288,
total_physical_size: 5941160,
total_available_size: 4339910624,
used_heap_size: 4768632,
heap_size_limit: 4345298944,
malloced_memory: 8192,
peak_malloced_memory: 582752,
does_zap_garbage: 0,
number_of_native_contexts: 2,
number_of_detached_contexts: 0
}

Azure container apps:

{
total_heap_size: 6053888,
total_heap_size_executable: 524288,
total_physical_size: 5531176,
total_available_size: 4340732928,
used_heap_size: 4294696,
heap_size_limit: 4345298944,
malloced_memory: 8192,
peak_malloced_memory: 582752,
does_zap_garbage: 0,
number_of_native_contexts: 2,
number_of_detached_contexts: 0
}

Can someone explain why this is happening and suggest possible solutions to address this issue?
Thank you in advance.

The discrepancy in memory behavior between Azure Container Apps and Docker containers likely because of differences in resource allocation and memory management in these environments. By increasing memory limits, adjusting heap sizes, and optimizing your application's memory usage, you can mitigate the out-of-memory errors in Azure Container Apps.
Assuming you have built and pushed your application to the container app

Adjust (increases the maximum heap size to 3GB) the app's heap size to prevent out-of-memory errors by setting the NODE_OPTIONS environment variable as below-
az containerapp update \
    --name my-node-app \
    --resource-group arkorg \
    --set-env-vars NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=3072"


You can even monitor the same using
az monitor metrics list \
    --resource /subscriptions/<Subscription-ID>/resourceGroups/arkorg/providers/Microsoft.App/containerApps/my-node-app \
    --metric "MemoryWorkingSetBytes" \
    --interval PT1M

now test it, you should not get the JavaScript heap out of memory error.

References:

Use memory efficiently for Java apps in Azure Container Apps
Memory use in high-level applications (visual-studio vs-code cli)


I have tried using NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096" in my container app which is 4cpu and 8GB. But when the Memory Working Set Bytes reaches around 4.2GB I receive the same FATAL ERROR: JavaScript heap out of memory. But this is not happening in my Docker container in which the same NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096" is set.
